# Can I change the mouse sensitivity for the X and Y axes individually?

Tags: battlefield-3

When flying the jet I have a hard time pitching up or down because of how slowly the jet reacts to movement along the Y axis.  I also have a hard time rolling left or right because of how quickly the jet reacts to movement along the X axis.  While this might make it easier to please [Peppy](https://www.google.com/search?q=do%20a%20barrel%20roll), it makes flying the jet difficult.

Is there any way I can increase the mouse sensitivity along the Y axis and decrease it along the X axis?  Can this be done to affect the jet alone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All available `Battlefield 3` settings can be found in the [Realmware BF3 Settings Editor](http://bf3.realmware.co.uk/settings-editor/) and there is no way to adjust mouse sensitivity for separate axis:

[image]
[image]

However, if you have a branded mouse, you can try to download their utility and to make changes there. Also, I think that there is a way to change axis sensitivity by editing some values in the Windows Registry, but, obviously, that isn't what you are looking for.